# Making an array whose elements are defined by a struct

Tags: c, multithreading

This might be a basic question for C. I'm making a struct called `check_t` and I want to make an array whose elements are of type `check_t`. This array is called `enqueued`. The struct `check_t` contains an integer x and a lock (for multi-threading).

```
typedef struct _check_t{
  int x;
  pthread_mutex_t lock;
} check_t;

void *check_init(check_t *c)
  c->x = 0;
  pthread_mutex_init(&c->lock,NULL);
}

check_t **enqueued;
for(i=0;i<w*h;i++){
  enqueued[i] = (check_t *)malloc(sizeof(check_t));
  check_init(&enqueued[i]);
}
```

Mostly, I'm wondering if this is the correct way to make/allocate space for an array of `check_t`s.

Comment: `check_t **enqueued;` is how you'd declare a pointer to a 2D array of `check_t`. Is that what you want?

Comment: enqueued is supposed to be a 1D array. However, I know that I need to stars; one to make it an array, and the other to indicate that I want pointers to each check_t. I can't do enqueued[i] if I say check_t *enqueued.

Comment: `*enqueued` and `enqueued[0]` mean the same thing.

Comment: You probably want the return type of check_init to be defined as void and not void* as well, since you're not returning anything from that method.

Answer (score 5):

1D array:

```
check_t *enqueued = malloc(N * sizeof(*enqueued));
enqueued[0].x = 5;
enqueued[N - 1].x = 2;
```

2D array:

```
check_t **enqueued = malloc(N * sizeof(*enqueued));
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    enqueued[i] = malloc(M * sizeof(**enqueued));
enqueued[0][0].x = 5;
enqueued[N - 1][M - 1].x = 2;
```

Comment: I'm much more familiar with spelling the `sizeof` parts as `sizeof(struct check_t)` than `sizeof(*[*]enqueued)`, but I've used similar approaches for `countof` style macros. Interesting.

Comment: It's safer in case `enqueued` changes types. From `check_t` to some other `struct`, for example.

Comment: @Bit Fiddling Code Monkey I concur about the `A = malloc(N *sizeof *A)` idiom.  But then why not `enqueued[i] = malloc(M * sizeof *(enqueued[i]))`?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, decide whether your program *actually* needs to be C and not C++. It's much safer and generally easier to use a std::vector<check_t> than a manually allocated region, as std::vector does automatic memory management for you (it makes it hard to memory leak) and it makes it hard to index the vector outside of bounds, which would cause a potentially exploitable memory corruption vulnerability in your program.

If for some reason you *must* do this without the standard template, next decide whether you can't use *new[]* in C++. This will simplify your code and be more clear what you're doing:

```
void main()
{
   check_t* myArray = new check_t[count];
}
```

Finally, if you're *absolutely positively 100% sure* you can't use std::vector or *new[]*, ask yourself if you can do it via *calloc*:

```
void main()
{
   check_t* myArray = calloc(nElements, sizeof(check_t));
}
```

But if, heaven forbid, you're doing some assignment that explicitly states that *you must use* ***malloc*** on pain of death that you ever use any of the multiple better alternatives that have so kindly been made available to you, this is how you do it:

```
#include <a_safe_int_library.h>
check_t* CreateAndInitializeCheckTArray
(
   /* IN */ size_t nElements
)
{
   size_t cbSize;
   check_t* array = NULL;
   size_t i;

   // avoid an exploitable integer/heap overflow first:
   if(SafeMultiply(&cbSize, sizeof(check_t), nElements) == OVERFLOW) 
       return NULL;

   array = (check_t*)malloc(cbSize);
   if(array == NULL)
      return NULL;

   // clear all of the elements:
   memset(array, 0, cbSize);

   // initialize the array:
   for(i = 0; i < nElements; i++)
   {
     check_init(&array[i]);
   }

   return array;
}
```